# establishing a rails path dynamically with object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `trace` table has the following columns: `model`  and `objectid`.

The goal is to create a link to the object.  The following syntax fails on two levels

```
link_to @trace.name,  "#{@trace.model.to_s}" + "_path(id: #{@trace.objectid})"
```

the string is being rendered incorrectly for processing by rails; in addition, rails interprets the path to its own class

```
/traces/categoryminor_path(id:%205)
```

and not

```
/categoryminors/5
```

How can this link be properly generated?

Comment: you are just doing string interpolation, try this - `link_to @trace.name, send("#{@trace.model.to_s}_path", id: @trace.objectid)`

Comment: Ah!  `public_send`  the useful sauce.

Comment: agree @Jerome `public_send` is preferred in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `send` to build the dynamic path

```
link_to @trace.name, send("#{@trace.model.to_s}_path", id: @trace.objectid)
```

OR as it is public method `public_send` is preferred.

```
link_to @trace.name, public_send("#{@trace.model.to_s}_path", id: @trace.objectid)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add eval before the string

```
    eval("#{@trace.model.to_s}" + "_path(id: #{@trace.objectid})")
```

This will form route as

```
    /categoryminors?id=5
```

Comment: One needs to be careful with `eval`, so I'd not suggest it to devs when the result can be achieved without it: `public_send("#{@trace.model.to_s}_path", id: @trace.object_id)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and from your comment I have learnt new concept. @Grzegorz